# Empty Output When I Put Scanf in C

Tags: css, input, output

I made a simple code in VS Code, hello world, then I run and it worked.  Next, I added an input, scanf.  But when I run the code, the output is empty.  The output doesn't show anything and only says "running".  Please help me solve this.

First code (success):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Second code (failed):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int pin;
    printf("Hello World");
    scanf("%d", &pin);
    return 0;
}
```

My code just accept printf, not scanf. If I add scanf, the output is empty and keep running. If I remove scanf and only printf in my code, is successful.

Comment: @Kartika Diva Asmara Gita Use puts("Hello World");  instead of printf ("Hello World");

Comment: @Some programmer dude I have add \n after Hello World. Isn't main problem. In second code, the output should display Hello World then I can type / input number for pin. But, the output is empty, even the sentence Hello World is not printed. But, there is no error message, it only says running... so I have to press ctrl+alt+m to stop running.

Comment: What happens in the second case, if you enter a number and press Enter?

Comment: @the busybee I can't press / type anything. It should display Hello World then i can type number. But, it's empty Output. If Hello World not appear, how can i input number

Comment: What are you using, an IDE, if so which, or a terminal or command prompt? -- Even if "Hello World" is not shown, you could try to enter something blindly.

Comment: @the busybee i use VS Code and i have set everything is needed for C like mingw and other extensions.

Comment: Aside: don't use an `int` for a "number" like pin, card, phone, house etc. These aren't integers, but strings. One major drawback of using an integer, is that you can't store leading zeros, which are significant. The pin 1234 isn't one thousand, two hundred and thirty four, but one-two-three-four.

Comment: @Weather Vane the main problem, output is empty. In the first code, it can printed Hello World. But in the second code, It should printed Hello World then i can input number for pin. But it's empty, even the sentence Hello World is not printed. If in my code there's Scanf, the output empty. I only can use printf in my code at all, not scanf even just one

Comment: That's why it was a comment starting with 'Aside'. I suggest that you try `printf("Hello World "); fflush(stdout);` Note I also added a space so the input you type is separated from the prompt.

Comment: @Weather Vane thankful. I will try it

Comment: So this is more an IDE problem, your C source should work fine, at least if you add `'\n'` or `fflush()`. IDEs are known to have problems with their console views. -- What happens if you run the executable in the command prompt window, not in the IDE?

Comment: @the busybee it can't work in command prompt. It closed suddenly

Comment: How that, did you simply double click the executable? Please add in detail what you tried by [edit]ing your question, please. I have no problem with your source, it works as shown.

Answer (score 2):

The `printf` function writes to `stdout`. When `stdout` is connected to a terminal or console, it's *line buffered*.

Line buffering means that the output is actually written to the terminal/console on either of three conditions:

1. The buffer is full
2. The buffer is explicitly flushed with `fflush(stdout)`
3. A newline is printed.

Your output:

```
printf ("Hello World");
```

doesn't fulfill any of the three conditions.

Simple solution is to add a trailing newline in the output you print:

```
printf ("Hello World\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you have not told your code to actually do anything with the scanf, that's maybe why nothing has come up on your terminal. scanf only takes input from the terminal, but it will not spit it out without you telling it to.

you will need to include this line of code for that to happen:

```
printf("%d", pin); // underneath your scanf line.
```

Comment: if so, i have to declare the pin.  I've set a number for the pin.  but i want to create a code that asks the user to enter numbers so i have to use scanf

Comment: @KartikaDivaAsmaraGita yes, you have already declared 'pin' in the second piece of code. And as someprogrammerdude said you need to add a '\n' for the 'hello world' line